# OUD 12c integration with OIM 12c

Tags: oracle12c, oim

I want to fetch all the users from OUD 12c to OIM 12c. Although I could do that when the OUD 12c was setup with the database but now the OUD installed on my machine does not have a database/RCU configuration. So now I am not able to fetch the users. Can anyone please help me with this.
These were the steps I followed to integrate OUD and OIM -

1. Install OID connector
2. Create target and authoritative applications
3. Run the jobs in the scheduler

Am I missing any steps? Please help. Thank you :)

Comment: What are the issues you see when you run trusted source recon against OUD?

Comment: Actually I cannot see anything in oim_server.out.. It gives the following output when I use the tail -f oim_server.out command :
"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f57f0029800 nid=0x15aec runnable
"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f57f002b000 nid=0x15aed runnable
"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f57f002d000 nid=0x15aee runnable
"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f57f2ad6800 nid=0x15b09 waiting on condition
What could possibly be the cause of not showing any logs? 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: try to see if `..-diagnostic.log` has more information. But I think it's bit off-topic here

Comment: I was able to resolve that issue. This is the error that I am getting when I run trusted source recon:
Application Instance Name ::OUDTarget
<Error> <ORG.IDENTITYCONNECTORS.LDAP.SEARCH.LDAPSEARCH> <BEA-000000> <org.identityconnectors.ldap.search.LdapSearch : execute : Perf: Search operation started >
<Error><ORG.IDENTITYCONNECTORS.LDAP.SEARCH.LDAPINTERNALSEARCH> <BEA-000000><org.identityconnectors.ldap.search.LdapInternalSearch : execute : Perf: Executing the search operation started>

Comment: should be something else, it doesn't look like a real error

Comment: Hi. The issue has been resolved. It seems the domain configuration was not done correctly hence the issue. Thank you for all your help :)